# What mistake do I have in my routing code?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

```
Route::get('student/{id}', 'StudentController@show');
Route::post('student/store', 'StudentController@store');
```

The route `student/store` barely work! because the first route `student/{id}` has the same structure of
`student/store` route with variable parameter. For example:
If you try to run the second route `student/store`, the run goes to the first route
`student/{id}`, and the first route take store as string parameter in `{id}`.

Comment: they are 2 different HTTP methods so they should not conflict with one another (if they are you are not using the correct HTTP methods or your webserver/proxy isn't setup correctly) ... if they were the same HTTP method you could try changing the order of the routes defined

Comment: Just move the second route definition to come before the first. Because ```/{id}``` can also include ```/store``` since ```/{id}``` is a wildcard. This is irrespective of the HTTP verb.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different **HTTP methods(get and post**) in two routes.
So when you will use (student/parameter) for a get request it will work for

> *Route::get('student/{id}', 'StudentController@show') route.*

And when you will use (student/store) for a post method it will work for

> *Route::post('student/store', 'StudentController@store');*

So, there is no mistake. Everything will work perfectly.